# Validate list of regular expressions to ensure no input pattern can match multiple expressions

Tags: regex

We have a configuration file containing a set of regular expressions that our program matches files against, and a rule that gets triggered if a match is found.

So if the configuration file contains:

`^\d{5}\.bat$|RULE23
^\d{3}\.txt$|RULE45`

the program would iterate through these expressions and match files which are for example 12345.bat triggering RULE23 to say move a file, and 321.txt triggering rule45 to execute a script on that file, but not acting on 1234567.bat.

All good in theory. In reality this configuration file contains say 100 expressions which can be edited by lots of people.

Is there a way for us to check if any of these expressions in the file overlap with another expression in the file (as this would likely be a configuration error)?

So for example if the configuration file was:

`^\d{5}\.bat$|RULE23
^\d{3}\.txt$|RULE45
\d{1}\.t|RULE50`

we'd like to run some code, which would check the config file and report that 
`^\d{3}\.txt$|RULE45
\d{1}\.txt|RULE50`
overlap, ie a filename with 3 numbers then .txt would match rule45 and rule50.

I've tried searching online, but it's difficult to phrase the problem without getting issues people have matching regular expressions which isn't quite this problem.

Any thoughts about how to go about proactively validating this list to ensure no possible pattern would match multiple rules?

Comment: A tag for your environment may be helpful. Bash? Windows CMD / PowerShell?

Comment: A rigorous, absolute check could be very difficult... But you could always run a set of unit tests against the regexes? I.e. "Each string in this list should be matched by at most one of the following regexes..." - and then you supply a long list of example strings?

Comment: We're happy to do the check in Linux, Windows, using Java, Python, C basically whatever.

Comment: We can run through example cases, but of course their usefulness will be limited by the set of examples you pick so it's quite a limited check.

Comment: Would it be an option to always try all expressions on every file and raise a runtime exception if more than one matches? (What you ask for, statically checking whether multiple regexes share common prefixes, is possible, but would take quite some time to implement correctly and I know of no existing implementation.)

Comment: Yes it would be possible to generate a runtime exception, but ideally we were hoping that we could proactively detect these logical errors before they generate production issues.

Comment: could you add real life example of the regexes you use?